# Without (much) calculation find two loci

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

The title pretty much says it. The problem I am trying to solve, is to find the loci of the expressions:

$$\text{a) $\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{z-{(1+i)}}{z+(1+i)}\right)=0$}\quad  \text{and}\quad    \text{b) $\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{z-{(1+i)}}{z+(1+i)}\right)=0$}$$

keeping the amount of calculation to a minimum.(For reference the problem can also be found in the "Art and Craft of problem solving" by Paul Zeitz p. 135 problem 4.2.9)

I really have no idea how to solve it, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes. I think they are isolate cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equally implies that the angle between $z-(1+i)$ and $z+(1+i)$ is $\pi/2$, implying that $z$ lies on the circumference of the circle whose diameter has endpoints $1+i$ and $-(1+i)$.

The second equality implies the angle between $z-(1+i)$ and $z+(1+i)$ is a multiple of $\pi$, implying that $z$ lies on the line joining $1+i$ and $-(1+i)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't quite understand why the two complex numbers should be perpendicular in case a) and I also don't understand why the angle between the two numbers in b) should be a multiple of pi. Could you explain how you came to that conclusion? Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry now I think I understand! If one writes the complex numbers as r(cosx + i*sinx) and s(cosy + i*siny), then the condition a) implies that cosx/cosy = 0. Hence cosx = 0, which occurs when x=pi/2... Am I right?!

Comment: Note that $arg(a/b)=arg(a)-arg(b)$ which is the angle between the vectors $a$ and $b$. Now a complex number whose real part is $0$ is purely imaginary and has argument $\pi/2$, while a complex number whose imaginary part is $0$ is a real number, which has as argument a multiple of $\pi$

Comment: Exactly you got it right.

Comment: Ah OK thanks! But why do we have the described circle and line in a) and b) respectively? Thanks

Comment: See that $a-b$ is the vector from $b$ towards $a$. So in the first case the vector joining $z$ and $1+i$ is at right angles to the vector joining $-(1+i)$ to $z$. As the diameter subtends a right angle on the circumference of the circle, hence the conclusion in first case.

Comment: Thank you I finally got it! (took some time didn't it... :D)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case with
$${\bf Re}\dfrac{z+a}{z-a}=\dfrac{|z|^2-|a|^2}{|z-a|^2}=0$$
shows $|z|=|a|$ where $z\neq a$. So $|z|=|-1-i|$ where $z\neq -1-i$ is a circle $|z|=\sqrt{2}$ except $z\neq -1-i$. Other case is similar.